# Efficiently validate uniqueness on elements of text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, validation, activerecord

So I have a `product` model which has a text property of newline separated `tags`. The reason behind this is that there is a query that runs daily that iterates through each of these fields building a regular expression by product and I want that to be as quick as possible. The products are only added or updated about once every few months, so the validation doesn't need to be as efficient, but I want to be as good as it can be given the previous restriction.

So far what I've come up with is this:

```
def build_regex_string
  '(' + tags.gsub(/(\r?\n(?!$))/,'|').gsub(/(\r?\n)/,'') + ')'
end

def validate_tags_are_unique
  Product.where.not(id: id).each do |product|
    tags_regex = Regexp.new(product.build_regex_string)
    return false if tags_regex.match(tags)
  end
end
```

I'm using regular expressions mostly because it's a method I already have. I was trying to look into whether writing the validation directly into the migration in pSQL would be a better idea? I'm not well versed in that. The other thing I looked into was using the array type instead, but I haven't found an ActiveRecord validation that does what I want with an array and I don't want to waste time building and unbuilding the array. Lastly I considered ways to actually store the regex in the database, but it looks like either way I would have to build the regex out of a string.

Comment: how slow is your current code that you need to optimize?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Ruby for this? It's so simple in Ruby.

```
def validate_tags_are_unique
  self_tags = tags.split(/\n/)
  Product.where.not(id: id).tags.all?{ |t| (self_tags - t.split(/\n/)).empty? }
end
```

Comment: It won't work properly, because Product.where.not(id: id) returns collection which doesn't have tags property.

Comment: Product.where.not(id: id).all? { |prod| (self_tags & prod.tags.split(/\n/)).empty? } is more correct (all products don't have common tags with the tags of the current product)

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: "-" operator won't work here. ["a", "b", "c"] - [] => ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"] - ["b"] => ["a", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"] - ["a", "b", "c"] => [].